# djapian based search freezes

Tags: django, xapian

When I try to run a djapian based search it freezes the applications and I dont get any response from the server. Am deploying the site using mod_wsgi. The search runs fine when i run it in the python shell or in the django dev server. The problem seems to arise only when I deploy my site to apache. Does anyone know how I can get around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when I started using Djapian. You should be able to work around this problem by adding the following to your Apache site 
configuration file:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

More information on the subject is available here: http://trac.xapian.org/ticket/185 and there's a related ticket for Djapian here: http://code.google.com/p/djapian/issues/detail?id=35